# I'am getting error while sending SOAP web service a post requirest with cURL

Tags: php, web, curl, service

I am trying to get info with soap web service but it is giving me an error `Request format is invalid: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------b35e9c9f375db7a5.`

```
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $servicepassword = $_POST['servicePassword'];
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://webgov.com.tr/WebService/Kontrol.asmx/PasoSorguKontrol',
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => [
        'id' => $id,
        'servicepassword' => $servicepassword
        ],
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
        ));
        $resp = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        echo $resp;
```

this web service need two variables to work, student id and web service password. and giving xml output. i could not make the code working. i am a newbie btw.

Comment: The message is clear enough: you're sending the wrong format. You haven't said what the required format is, so there's little more to say.

Comment: I would recommend trying with PHP's [SoapClient](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) instead of handling all of it manually.

Comment: i can not use SoapClient because i can not change php.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is using `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`. I even make a function with this codes and it solved my problem.

```
function httpPost($url,$params) {
    $postData = '';
    foreach($params as $k => $v) {
        $postData .= $k . '='.$v.'&';
    }
    rtrim($postData, '&');
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);

    $output=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}
```